# Resizing image and running out of memory

Tags: php, image, memory, resize, jpeg

I'm currently building an import-module for Prestashop. This module is importing about 3000 products and needs to resize every product-image to 5 different thumbnail-formats. The problem is: the script consumes A LOT of memory. I'm talking about 100 MB peak and up to 27 MB during the process. I'm kind of ashamed to say I'm not very familiar with the whole memory-managing stuff, so any help is welcome!

The code I'm using is the following. The resizeImg method should be the most interesting, the other methods are just for illustration on how I'm processing the tasks. Does anyone know why I get a memory peak of over 100MB?

```
public function main() {
    foreach( $products as $product ) {
        self::copyImg( $imageURL );
    }
}

static private function copyImg( $imageURL ) {
    // Copy image from $imageURL to temp folder

    foreach( $imageTypes as $type ) {
        self::resizeImg( $tempImage, $destination, $type['width'], $type['height']);
    }
}

static private function resizeImg( $sourceFile, $destFile, $destWidth, $destHeight )
{
    list( $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $sourceFile );
    if ( is_null( $destWidth ) ) $destWidth = $sourceWidth;
    if ( is_null( $destHeight ) ) $destHeight = $sourceHeight;

    $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg( $sourceFile );
    $widthDiff = $destWidth / $sourceWidth;
    $heightDiff = $destHeight / $sourceHeight;

    if ( $widthDiff > 1 && $heightDiff > 1 ) {

        $nextWidth = $sourceWidth;
        $nextHeight = $sourceHeight;

    } else {

        if ( Configuration::get( 'PS_IMAGE_GENERATION_METHOD' ) == 2 || ( ! Configuration::get( 'PS_IMAGE_GENERATION_METHOD' ) AND $widthDiff > $heightDiff ) ) {

            $nextHeight = $destHeight;
            $nextWidth = round( $sourceWidth * $nextHeight / $sourceHeight );
            $destWidth = ( ! Configuration::get( 'PS_IMAGE_GENERATION_METHOD' ) ? $destWidth : $nextWidth );

        } else {

            $nextWidth = $destWidth;
            $nextHeight = round( $sourceHeight * $destWidth / $sourceWidth );
            $destHeight = ( ! Configuration::get( 'PS_IMAGE_GENERATION_METHOD' ) ? $destHeight : $nextHeight );

        }

    }

    $destImage = imagecreatetruecolor( $destWidth, $destHeight );
    $white = imagecolorallocate( $destImage, 255, 255, 255 );
    imagefilledrectangle( $destImage, 0, 0, $destWidth, $destHeight, $white );
    imagecopyresampled( $destImage, $sourceImage, ( ( $destWidth - $nextWidth ) / 2 ), ( ( $destHeight - $nextHeight ) / 2 ), 0, 0, $nextWidth, $nextHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight );
    imagecolortransparent( $destImage, $white );
    imagejpeg( $destImage, $destFile, 90 );

    imagedestroy( $sourceImage );
    imagedestroy( $destImage );
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm struggling with the same thing in a Prestashop module

Comment: I do not remember how we solved this issue. Most likely we took a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just how big are these images? Remember that once they're loaded into GD, they're uncompressed into 3 (or 4) bytes per pixel. 100mb at 24bit is enough for a 6666x5000 or so image. Have you checked that the resizing calculations are working correctly? If they're wrong, you could be trying to create a massively large 'dest' image by mistake.

I don't see where you're writing out the resized image, either. There's lots of resizing/copying, but nowhere do you have `imagejpeg()` or `imagepng()` etc... to write out the resized image.

Comment: Hi Marc. All images have the exact size of 500x500px. Correct me if I'm wrong. I guess this means one image is 250.000 pixels. After GD uncompresses it, 250.000 * 4 = 1 mln bytes which is approximately 1MB. But I'm constantly cleaning these resources in my loop, so why do I get a peak of 100MB? P.s: modified my code for imagejpeg-method!

Comment: hard to say. I can't spot any resource leaks offhand. Try sprinkling some `echo memory_get_usage(true)` calls before/after the various calls to see where the usage is shooting upwards.

Comment: The usage isn't shooting upwards anywhere in particular. I notice that after downloading and resizing a few images, another memory block of 256 or 512 KB gets reserved, but nothing more. The problem is: after about 10.000 times of executing that piece of code, those blocks of 265 KB will increase the used memory to abnormal heights.